# Is it possible to load the parameters of a single object using LoadQuery()

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am working on a project where the ClientContext might be active for a long time. To prevent memory usage getting out of hand I would like to use `ClientContext.LoadQuery()` instead of `ClientContext.Load()` when getting items from SharePoint.

`LoadQuery` works very well when loading lists of items such as `Web.Lists` or `Web.Webs` but I haven't found a way to load a single object such as `ClientContext.Web`. Loading a single website with `Load()` I would use the following:

```
string relativeUrl = "/mysite";
Web web = ctx.Site.OpenWebUsingPath( relativeUrl );
ctx.Load(web, w => w.Title);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

With `LoadQuery()` I had hoped I could do something like

```
string relativeUrl = "/mysite";
Web tmpWeb = ctx.Site.OpenWebUsingPath( relativeUrl );
Web web = ctx.LoadQuery(tmpWeb, w => w.Title);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

That is not possible since `LoadQuery` takes either `IQueryable<T>` or `ClientObjectCollection<T>` as input.

Is there any way to get the web object without having it bound to to the client context and using unnecessary memory?

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**:

Consider disposing of the context and creating a new one after calls to context.Load as a way to manage memory of objects cached in the context.

**Research notes:**

There does not appear to be an easy way to convert from a `ClientObject` to a `ClientObjectCollection<T>`.  Here is what I tried unsuccessfully incase anyone else wants to research further:

Creating an appropriate descended of `ClientObjectCollection<T>` and populating it with the `ObjectPath` of the `ClientObject` produces syntactically correct code which isn't supported by the server and generally returns "Invalid operation" error from `ExecuteQuery`.

e.g.

```
string relativeUrl = "/mysite";
Web tmpWeb = ctx.Site.OpenWebUsingPath( relativeUrl );
WebCollection wc = new WebCollection(ctx,tmpWeb.Path);
ctx.LoadQuery(wc.Include( w=>w.Title ));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

compiles but fails when executed.

It is notable that `DataRetrieval.Load<T>` (which is what `ClientContext.Load<T>` calls) does the following on it's first line:

```
ClientObjectCollection objectCollection = (object) clientObject as ClientObjectCollection;
```

But this is the non-generic base class for `ClientObjectCollection<T>`